# Couldn't read tsconfig.base.json! - Apollo Angular project setup

Tags: angular, apollo-client, graphql-js

```
ng add apollo-angular
```

It threw a number of warnings:

```
UPDATE src/app/app.module.ts (541 bytes)
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for extract-files@9.0.0: wanted: {"node":"^10.17.0 || ^12.0.0 || >= 13.7.0"} (current: {"node":"10.16.3","npm":"6.12.0"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: extract-files@9.0.0
npm WARN karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.5.4 requires a peer of jasmine-core@>=3.5 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @apollo/client@3.1.3 requires a peer of react@^16.8.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @apollo/client@3.1.3 requires a peer of subscriptions-transport-ws@^0.9.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

So after adding the peer dependencies I try to add apollo-angular one more time:

```
MIA-LT-16354:src SSilwal$ ng add apollo-angular
Skipping installation: Package already installed
? Url to your GraphQL endpoint https://o5x5jzoo7z.sse.codesandbox.io/graphql'
Couldn't read tsconfig.base.json!
```

Environment:

@apollo/client: 3.0.0
apollo-angular:2.0.3
graphql:15.3.0
@angular/core:9.1.7
@angular/cli: 9.1.12
typescript:3.8.3

Comment: You're not alone on this one, i have the same problem

Comment: No, i'm really stuck on this one ...

Comment: Same here folks, any update?

Comment: I updated to  "apollo-angular": "^2.0.4" and I was also in the process of upgrading my angular project to angular 10.  After all these updates it worked. 
Here is the link to this issue that I had raised. 
https://github.com/kamilkisiela/apollo-angular/issues/1554

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue usually happens when your Angular project had a version migration before, so that the `tsconfig.base.json` is missing or not valid.

You can try installing `apollo-angular` manually as the official document guides itself

[Apollo Angular official guide](https://apollo-angular.com/docs/1.0/basics/setup#installation-without-angular-schematics)  on installing `apollo-angular` without Angular schematics

or follow this manual updates I mention below:

---

The Github issue raised by the author of the question offers a fix by only updating the angular version, try this first

During the time I was facing this problem using the command below had helped some people but didn't solve mine

it's free to try

```
ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from 9 --to 10
ng update @angular/core --migrate-only --from 9 --to 10
```

*or try using --force if you faced errors (Use With Caution !!)*

It's the solution offered to fix  `tsconfig.base.json` problems caused by migrating Angular version

Main Source : [Github issue related to this question](https://github.com/kamilkisiela/apollo-angular/issues/1554)

**Note that it has some side effects**

Read more at [Angulars Official Docs](https://update.angular.io/?v=9.0-10.0) about how to migrate properly based of how complex your project is

---

I personally used this command to install all packages needed and proceeded with the guide to add needed modules.

```
ng update apollo-angular --migrate-only --from 1.10.0
```

*or try using --force if you faced errors (Use With Caution !!)*

```
ng update apollo-angular --migrate-only --from 1.10.0 --force
```

I hope this helped :)

---

P.S in some countries such as Iran, you might need to use a proxy to use
`ng add apollo-angular`

Comment: in the steps that I mention in the answer, I was forced to install some dependencies manually. don't be afraid to use ```--force``` or installing extra packages if you are familiar with git and version managing

Comment: I also ended up updating angular to 10, you can check my comment on the initial post.  It worked that way.

Comment: yes, so did I. the GitHub issue you mentioned was helpful thanks. i updated the answer to include the link